# d3.json() fail but jQuery $.getJSON() work correctly with same URL and php code

Tags: php, json, get, download, d3.js

i work with d3.js and CodeIgniter and i have a problem when i get json data with d3.json
when i run this code :

```
var url = "http://probe.dev/draw/windRose?station=vp2&sensors=wind&Since=2012-10-15T00:00:00&StepUnit=DAY&StepNbr=6;
d3.json(url, function(d) {
    console.log(d); // print NULL in console
}
```

but it works with

```
$.getJSON(url, function(d) {
    console.log(d); // print my data object correctly
}
```

my php code is :

```
<?php
@ob_end_clean();
 header('Content-Type: "application/json"');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.json"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
  exit($data);
```

I don't understand why d3.json do not work ?

Comment: Have you tried without the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers? `$.getJSON` is a more fully fleshed out loading mechanism than `d3.json`, and `d3.json` might not be able to deal with these headers.

Comment: Make sure you are using the right D3 version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13621132/760156

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't make it work with v2, I moved to [d3js.v3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/v3.0.3) and it worked.

The callback function in v3 takes two params:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    else ...;
}
```