# D3 chart example "TypeError: data is undefined"

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, linechart, csv

I am working with the D3 chart example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. Everything is working as planned, but I am getting `TypeError: data is undefined` on the second line of the following code:

```
d3.tsv(tsvDataURL, function(error, data) {
               data.forEach(function(d) {
                            d.time = parseDate(d.time);
                            d["temperature [C]"] = +d.["temperature [C]"];
                            });
```

The question here deals with an almost identical issue [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612130/d3-js-simple-area-chart-example-getting-undefined-error-i-think-i-need-a), but it did not seem to solve the problem for me. I know that tsvDataURL is correct, and I can open up the tsv from my browser. How can I fix this error?

Comment: If you're running this locally, you need a webserver.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I am running it locally, but I cannot set up a webserver in my current situation. For what reason do I need one?

Comment: It's because of security restrictions, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm running this with python simple http. does that count as a web server?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's used on the page I've linked to. Are you getting any errors in `error`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sorry, I has not read through all of the link. I did `console.log(error);` which displayed an object of type `XMLHTTPRequest`.

Comment: Does that contain an error message somewhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48996/discussion-between-68cherries-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had copy pasted both the code and the data to my laptop. But when copy pasting the data file, you don't get a proper .tsv file, since the website is rendered with spaces instead of tabs.

Instead download the tsv file from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3883245/data.tsv.